# What is a word for the phrase "it is necessary" in analogy with the relation between "suffices" and "it is sufficient"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs, synonyms

I am aware that "it suffices that" can be used in place with "it is sufficient that"; for instance, one may use "To stay alive, it suffices that we keep breathing." (taken as merely formal) to mean "To stay alive, it is sufficient that we keep breathing.".

I wonder if there is a similar choice for the phrase "it is necessary that", in the sense that what "suffice" is to "be sufficient", this choice is to "be necessary".

Comment: To stay alive necessitates breathing. (In fact, breathing is not sufficient for life, but it is necessary. Pendants corner, sorry.)

Comment: @simonatrcl, Hi, thanks. I guess "necessitate" is close but not exactly what I am after as "to stay alive, it necessitates to breathe" does not sound right? By the way, the remark may be resolved by noticing the phrase "taken as merely formal". I just wanted to give an example of the form of interest without trying to make sense of it.

Comment: OK, you're now using a different phrase. If you want a phrase that fits the .pattern 'It X to breathe' then x = 'is necessary'; there is no single word that fits with the 'to' in there. 'It necessitates that we keep breathing' is OK, but these all sound clunky and rather artificial. I think you're over-specifying the structure you want rather than concentrating on the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: @simonatrcl, Hi, and for everyone who passes by, I am after and only after the formal aspect. I am sorry, but I am afraid I would have to disagree with most of your present words.

Comment: ٌI don not see anything informal with the verb "necessitate"? Why would you think it wouldn't be suitable for a formal piece of writing?

Comment: The only lack with "necessitates" is that it can't be used with a to-infinitive. It has to be used with a gerund or a clause.

Comment: @Cardinal, Hi, by "formal" I mean "regarding the form of things" or "appearance".

Answer (score 3):

The analogous word is [**necessitates**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necessitated):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : to make necessary : REQUIRE
>       // Business was growing, which *necessitated* the hiring of additional employees.
>   **2** : FORCE, COMPEL
>       // was *necessitated* to choose some other route

The following summarizes the examples and constructions from the question:

> It is **sufficient** <sup>[adjective]</sup> that we keep breathing.
> → It **suffices** <sup>[verb]</sup> that we keep breathing.
>
> It is **necessary** <sup>[adjective]</sup> that we keep breathing.
> → It ***necessitates*** <sup>[verb]</sup> that we keep breathing.

Different constructions can be made from the same words, but those are the verbal equivalents of the adjectives.

Note too that the different words require different constructions in specific contexts:

> To stay alive, it **suffices** that we keep breathing.
>   Staying alive **necessitates** that we keep breathing.